# Fast (faster than std::) ostringstream

Tags: c++, c++11, stream

I tried to implement a faster `ostringstream` which initially uses the stack (up to 256 bytes before using the heap).

Also, unlke the standard, it provides a way to access the data and size without creating new string each time, and supports copy and move ctors.

Please review.

```
#include <iomanip>    
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>

template<unsigned short STACK_SIZE>
class stack_buf
{
public:
    static const unsigned short stack_size = STACK_SIZE;
    stack_buf() :_v(), _stack_size(0) {}
    ~stack_buf() = default;
    stack_buf(const stack_buf& other):stack_buf(other, delegate_copy_move {})
    {}

    stack_buf(stack_buf&& other):stack_buf(other, delegate_copy_move {})
    {
        other.clear();
    }
    template<class T1>
    stack_buf& operator=(T1&& other)
    {
        _stack_size = other._stack_size;
        if (other.vector_used())
            _v = std::forward<T1>(other)._v;
        else
            std::copy_n(other._stack_array.begin(), other._stack_size, _stack_array.begin());
        return *this;
    }

    void append(const char* buf, std::size_t buf_size)
    {
        //If we are aleady using _v, forget about the stack
        if (vector_used())
        {
            _v.insert(_v.end(), buf, buf + buf_size);
        }
        //Try use the stack
        else
        {
            if (_stack_size + buf_size <= STACK_SIZE)
            {
                std::memcpy(&_stack_array[_stack_size], buf, buf_size);
                _stack_size += buf_size;
            }
            //Not enough stack space. Copy all to _v
            else
            {
                _v.reserve(_stack_size + buf_size);
                _v.insert(_v.end(), _stack_array.begin(), _stack_array.begin() + _stack_size);
                _v.insert(_v.end(), buf, buf + buf_size);
            }
        }
    }       
    void clear()
    {
        _stack_size = 0;
        _v.clear();
    }

    const char* data() const
    {
        if (vector_used())
            return _v.data();
        else
            return _stack_array.data();
    }

    std::size_t size() const
    {
        if (vector_used())
            return _v.size();
        else
            return _stack_size;
    }

private:
    struct delegate_copy_move {};
    template<class T1>
    stack_buf(T1&& other, delegate_copy_move)
    {
        _stack_size = other._stack_size;
        if (other.vector_used())
            _v = std::forward<T1>(other)._v;
        else
            std::copy_n(other._stack_array.begin(), other._stack_size, _stack_array.begin());
    }

    inline bool vector_used() const
    {
        return !(_v.empty());
    }

    std::vector<char> _v;
    std::array<char, STACK_SIZE> _stack_array;
    std::size_t _stack_size;
};

//
// Custom std::streambuf
//
class stack_devicebuf :public std::streambuf
{
public:
    static const unsigned short stack_size = 256;
    using stackbuf_t = stack_buf<stack_size>;

    stack_devicebuf() = default;
    ~stack_devicebuf() = default;

    stack_devicebuf(const stack_devicebuf& other) :std::basic_streambuf<char>(), _stackbuf(other._stackbuf)
    {}

    stack_devicebuf(stack_devicebuf&& other):
        std::basic_streambuf<char>(),
        _stackbuf(std::move(other._stackbuf))
    {
        other.clear();
    }

    stack_devicebuf& operator=(stack_devicebuf other)
    {
        std::swap(_stackbuf, other._stackbuf);
        return *this;
    }

    const stackbuf_t& buf() const
    {
        return _stackbuf;
    }
    std::size_t size() const
    {
        return _stackbuf.size();
    }

    void clear()
    {
        _stackbuf.clear();
    }

protected:
    // copy the given buffer into the accumulated fast buffer
    std::streamsize xsputn(const char_type* s, std::streamsize count) override
    {
        _stackbuf.append(s, static_cast<unsigned int>(count));
        return count;
    }

    int_type overflow(int_type ch) override
    {
        if (traits_type::not_eof(ch))
        {
            char c = traits_type::to_char_type(ch);
            xsputn(&c, 1);
        }
        return ch;
    }
private:
    stackbuf_t _stackbuf;
};

//
// fast ostringstream
//
class fast_oss :public std::ostream
{
public:
    fast_oss() :std::ostream(&_dev) {}
    ~fast_oss() = default;

    fast_oss(const fast_oss& other) :std::basic_ios<char>(), std::ostream(&_dev), _dev(other._dev)
    {}

    fast_oss(fast_oss&& other) :std::basic_ios<char>(), std::ostream(&_dev), _dev(std::move(other._dev))
    {
        other.clear();
    }


    fast_oss& operator=(fast_oss other)
    {
        swap(*this, other);
        return *this;
    }

    void swap(fast_oss& first, fast_oss& second) // nothrow
    {
        using std::swap;
        swap(first._dev, second._dev);
    }

    std::string str()
    {
        auto& buffer = _dev.buf();
        const char*data = buffer.data();
        return std::string(data, data+buffer.size());
    }

    const stack_devicebuf::stackbuf_t& buf() const
    {
        return _dev.buf();
    }

    std::size_t size() const
    {
        return _dev.size();
    }    
    void clear()
    {
        _dev.clear();
    }

private:
    stack_devicebuf _dev;
};
```

Comment: for `delegate_copy_move {}`, `gcc` gives me this: `error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction`

Comment: works for me (gcc 4.9)

Comment: alright, I'll upgrade tomorrow, nevermind then!

Comment: @Loki, i think this is what the code does.. see the stack_devicebuf class

Comment: @GabiMe: Sorry about that. Did not read far enough down.

Comment: The trick with `using std::swap;` I wonder why you decided not to use it with the other swap? Its a nice detail which I only recently saw, either here on stackexchange or on a cppcon 2014 video.

Comment: Did you ever do something (= publish a FOSS library) with a standalone stringstream impl?

Comment: @einpoklum No..

Answer (score 4):

Just some minor coding style issues that jump into the eye.

---

The ternary operator would make some of the methods shorter and sweeter:

```
const char* data() const
{
    return vector_used() ? _v.data() : _stack_array.data();
}

std::size_t size() const
{
    return vector_used() ? _v.size() : _stack_size;
}
```

---

The parentheses are unnecessary around `_v.empty()`:

> ```
> inline bool vector_used() const
> {
>     return !(_v.empty());
> }
> ```

---

<strike>Instead of:</strike>

> ```
> void swap(fast_oss& first, fast_oss& second) // nothrow
> {
>     using std::swap;
>     swap(first._dev, second._dev);
> }
> ```

Why not just:

```
void swap(fast_oss& first, fast_oss& second) // nothrow
{
    std::swap(first._dev, second._dev);
}
```

As per [@loki](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/507/loki-astari)'s [comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/67262/fast-faster-than-std-ostringstream/67306?noredirect=1#comment122759_67306):

> The reason for doing `using std::swap;` and then using `swap()` without the namespace is to force Koenig look-up of which swap to use. So the original version is correct.

Comment: Thanks. Have you got it to compile yet on gcc?

Comment: No, that's partly why it's hard to say more :( It's not a good time for me now to upgrade my gcc/g++.

Comment: on which version it doesn't compile?

Comment: @GabiMe on 4.2.1

Comment: @janos: The reason for doing `using std::swap;` and then using `swap()` without the namespace is to force `Koenig look-up` of which swap to use. So the original version is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I've looked at the following functions

```
template<class T1>
stack_buf& operator=(T1&& other) {
    _stack_size = other._stack_size;
    if (other.vector_used())
        _v = std::forward<T1>(other)._v;
    else
        std::copy_n(other._stack_array.begin(), other._stack_size, _stack_array.begin());
    return *this;
}
```

and

```
template<class T1>
stack_buf(T1&& other, delegate_copy_move) {
    _stack_size = other._stack_size;
    if (other.vector_used())
        _v = std::forward<T1>(other)._v;
    else
        std::copy_n(other._stack_array.begin(), other._stack_size, _stack_array.begin());
}
```

They got the same code except the added `return *this;` so they could be combined to:

```
template<class T1>
void rip_other(T1&& other) {
    _stack_size = other._stack_size;
    if (other.vector_used())
        _v = std::forward<T1>(other)._v; // call _v's  =(T&&)
    else
        std::copy_n(other._stack_array.begin(), other._stack_size, _stack_array.begin());
}

template<class T1>
stack_buf(T1&& other, delegate_copy_move) {
    rip_other(std::forward<T1>(other));
}

template<class T1>
stack_buf& operator=(T1&& other) {
    rip_other(std::forward<T1>(other));
    return *this;
}
```

By combining them you don't have to update 2 places when you make changes.

I first considered if it shouldn't be a swap operation as you call swap on stack_buf later, but the std::swap should make as good a work as if you did it yourself.